# Magento 2 get Store Id of a coupon code programmatically

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes, sales-rule

I am using **multiple stores**, I wanted to get all the **coupon code** of a particular **store**.

In Magento 2 database, `salesrule_website` **table** have **`stores`** related information, but their is no **model/collection** to get the data from this **table**.

Please guide me how to get store information of a **coupon code**, or I need to create my own model for `salesrule_website` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, Magento is not providing any Model or Collection for `salesrule_website` table.

So what I did to solve this issue is, I used mysql to get collection from that table.

**Code:**

```
$stringId = '10';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_website');
$sql = "Select website_id FROM " . $tableName ." Where rule_id IN ('".$stringId."')";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
if($result)
{
  // Your code goes here
}
```